# Getting the header name on extjs4 grid

Tags: extjs4

Im trying to get the column header for the cell im clicking, but im not finding the correct way to do it

Right now, im using this code to identify the column:

```
if (position.column == 5 /*this is column name*/)
```

Obviously this is a bad choice, since any change on the grid will have consequences on the code.

Once again, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Ext.Grid.Panel. There is a columns array that can be indexed into to give you the column definition. the "text" property will contain the displayed column name.

```
alert(gridPanel.columns[0].text); //Alerts the 1st columns' header text.
```

If this doesn't answer your question a little more context would be helpful. In which event are you capturing your position?

If you are trying to determine a better way to get your column position setting the grid's initial config selType property to 'cellmodel' will give you a [Ext.selection.CellModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel) selection model whose select event would give you the current cell position (col, row).

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [{
                id: 'common',
                header: 'Collumn 1'
            }, {
             header: 'Column 2'
            }
        ],
        selModel: {
            selType: 'cellmodel'
        }
    });
    grid.getSelectionModel().addListener('select', function(selModel, record, row, column, eOpts){
        alert(grid.columns[column].text);
    });
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot, i just had to change te [0] for [position.column] to find exactly the header of the column im clicking

Answer (score 0):

The best method might depend on where the code is, but here is some code from the `CellEditing` plugin which might be a good place to start:

```js
editColumnHeader = grid.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(position.column);
```

From there, `text` looks like it would work, you might also be able to use `itemId` if you set that in the column.